# What is the way of correct way in using calloc for an array?

Tags: c, pointers

I want to create a pointer to an array of pointers (with 10 pointers in the array), then I want to give a pointer a value.

This is what I have so far:

```
char **arraypointer = calloc (10, sizeof (char*));
```

How will I give value to this array?

I've tried:

```
arraypointer[0] = "string"
```

But I get a seg fault.

Edit:

I want to create a pointer that points to an array of pointers. Each of these pointers will have a struct property. How is it possible to access the struct property for this pointer? I have no code to post because I am still trying to figure out how it should look. The struct for this pointer will contain a string which is a char *string and an int number. I am thinking of it working like this:

```
arraypointer[0]->string = "this";
arraypointer[0]->number = 3;
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Post real code please.

Comment: The call to calloc is correct, the assignment also. So you most propably are getting the segmentation fault later in your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update:***

```
struct mystruct* pointer = calloc(N, sizeof(struct mystruct));
pointer[0].string = "this"; //notice . instead of ->
          ^
pointer[0].number = 3;
          ^
```

***Original answer:***

```
char **arraypointer = calloc (10, sizeof (char*));
arraypointer[0] = "string";
```

These two lines are perfectly fine. You'd get a segfault(Undefined behavior, actually) if you tried to do something like

```
arraypointer[0][3] = 's';
```

later.

Also, you'd get in trouble if you did

```
strcpy(arraypointer[0], "string");
```

because you haven't actually allocated any memory that `arraypointer[i]` point to

Comment: @diesel: Yes, -> is for pointers, but `pointer[0]` is not a pointer. `pointer` is

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My terminology is lacking, therefore it's hard for me to sometimes try and explain what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to type :

```
char **arraypointer = (char**) calloc (10, sizeof (char*));
```

As calloc is meant for void*

Answer (score 0):

```
//READING STRINGS USING POINTERS (CALLOC)   

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main() {

    int n;
    printf("Enter number of Strings : \n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    char** a = (char**) calloc(n, sizeof(char*));
    int i=0;
    printf("Enter Strings : \n");
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) {
        a[i]= (char*) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
        scanf("%s", a[i]);
    }

    i=0;
    printf("**************\n");
    for (i;i<n;i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```